# Java programming in Eclipse exporting error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

```
package ticketBook;
import java.util.*;

public class run {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        **Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)**;  "Resource leak: 'in' is never closed"
        int ch,i,n,movch; String rowch[]=new String[12];
        int colch[]=new int[12];
        String time = new String();
        String timecheck = new String();
        show objshow = new show();
        screen objscreen = new screen();
        ticket objticket = new ticket();
        while(true){
        System.out.println("\n\t\t   Movie Ticket Booking System\n");
        System.out.println("1.Book Movie Tickets");
        System.out.println("2.See Movies/Show Timings");
        System.out.println("3.Exit");
        System.out.println("\nAdvanced Bookings are closed as of now.");
        System.out.println("\nEnter Choice");
        ch = in.nextInt();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: objshow.display_show_timings();
                    System.out.println("Choose the Movie");
                    movch=in.nextInt();
                    do{
                    System.out.println("Enter Show timings (hh:mm)");
                    time=in.next();
                    timecheck=objshow.check_time(movch,time);
                    }while(timecheck.equals("false"));
                    System.out.println("Enter Number of seats");
                    n=in.nextInt();
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                        objscreen.display_seats();
                        rowch[i]=in.next().toUpperCase();
                        objshow.show_empty_seats(rowch[i],movch);
                        colch[i]=in.nextInt();
                        if(objshow.check_seats(rowch[i],colch[i],movch))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Seat is not available");
                        }
                        objshow.fill_seat(rowch[i],colch[i],movch);
                    }
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                                objticket.print_ticket(objshow.getmovie(movch), time, 3, objscreen.getcat(rowch[i]), rowch[i], colch[i]);
                    }
                    break;

            case 2: objshow.display_show_timings();
                    break;

            case 3: System.exit(0);         
        }
    }
    }
}
```

While exporting to executable Jar file it ends with error:

> Resource leak: 'in' is never closed.

Comment: I guess it is Not an error. It is only a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `try with resources`, which will automatically close the stream at the end of the try.

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
           // rest of the code. 
        } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you're using JDK6 or before:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
           // rest of the code. 
        } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
           in.close();
        }
    }
```